# Arrays Java - Trying to remove user input requirements

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a program that calculates rainfall for the year etc. I had the first block of code below working with the user input, perfectly. However, I am trying to change the program now, so that the array values are specified (I'm basically trying to eliminate the user input).

Why isn't the second block of code working? I am getting errors at the bottom for r.getTotalRainFall, r.getAverageRainFall etc.

Please note that I had to introduce the array thisYear (this is required).

CODE BLOCK #1:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rainfall {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int month = 12;
double total = 0;
double average;
double months[];

public Rainfall() {
    months = new double[12];
}

public void enterMonthData() {
    for (int n = 1; n <= month; n++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" + n + ": ");
        months[n - 1] = in.nextDouble();

        // Input Validation - Cannot accept a negative number
        while (months[n - 1] < 0) {
            System.out.print("Rainfall must be at least 0. Please enter a new value.");
            months[n - 1] = in.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}

public double getTotalRainFall() {
    total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        total = total + months[i];
    }
    return total;
}

public double getAverageRainFall() {
    average = total / 12;
    return average;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the month with the highest rainfall.
 */
public int getHighestMonth() {
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (months[i] > months[highest]) {
            highest = i;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the month with the lowest rainfall.
 */
public int getLowestMonth() {
    int lowest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (months[i] < months[lowest]) {
            lowest = i;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    Rainfall r = new Rainfall();
    r.enterMonthData();
    System.out.println("The total rainfall for this year is " + r.getTotalRainFall());
    System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is " + r.getAverageRainFall());
    int lowest = r.getLowestMonth();
    int highest = r.getHighestMonth();
    System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain is " + (highest+1) + " with " + r.months[highest] + " inches");
    System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain is  " + (lowest+1) + " with " + r.months[lowest] + " inches");
}
}
```

CODE BLOCK #2:

```
package rain;

public class Rain {

int month = 12;
double total = 0;
double average; 
double getRainAt[];

 public Rain {
    getRainAt = new double[12];
}

double getTotalRainFall() {
    total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        total = total + getRainAt[i];
    }
    return total;
}

   double getAverageRainFall() {
    average = total / 12;
    return average;
}

int getHighestMonth() {
    int high = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (getRainAt[i] > getRainAt[high]) {
            high = i;
        }
    }
    return high;
}

int getLowestMonth() {
    int low = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (getRainAt[i] < getRainAt[low]) {
            low = i;
        }
    }
    return low;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   // Create an array of rainfall figures.
  double[] thisYear = {1.6, 2.1, 1.7, 3.5, 2.6, 3.7,
                       3.9, 2.6, 2.9, 4.3, 2.4, 3.7 };

  int high;      // The high month
  int low;       // The low month

  // Create a RainFall object initialized with the figures
  // stored in the thisYear array.
  Rainfall r = new Rainfall(thisYear);

  // Display the statistics.
  System.out.println("The total rainfall for this year is " +
                     r.getTotalRainFall();
  System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is " +
                     r.getAverageRainFall());
  high = r.getHighestMonth();
  System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain " +
                     "is " + (high+1) + " with " + r.getRainAt(high) +
                     " inches.");
  low = r.getLowestMonth();
  System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain " +
                     "is " + (low+1) + " with " + r.getRainAt(low) +
                     " inches.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have re-factored the 2 classes

now Rain class only contains the main method whereas all the other logic is contained in the Rainfall class

Rainfall class has a method - getRainAt() to get rain base don the given month
in Rainfall class has a constructor that takes a double array as an argument so it has to be instantiated with this argument provided.

take a look at the classes now and see if this fits your requirement.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rainfall {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int month = 12;
double total = 0;
double average;
double months[];

public Rainfall(double newmonths[]){
    months = newmonths;
}

public void enterMonthData() {
    for (int n = 1; n <= month; n++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" + n
                + ": ");
        months[n - 1] = in.nextDouble();

        // Input Validation - Cannot accept a negative number
        while (months[n - 1] < 0) {
            System.out
                    .print("Rainfall must be at least 0. Please enter a new value.");
            months[n - 1] = in.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}

public double getTotalRainFall() {
    total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        total = total + months[i];
    }
    return total;
}

public double getAverageRainFall() {
    average = total / 12;
    return average;
}

/**
 * get rain given the month number
 */
public double getRainAt(int month){
    double rainValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        if(month == i){
            rainValue = months[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return rainValue;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the month with the highest rainfall.
 */
public int getHighestMonth() {
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (months[i] > months[highest]) {
            highest = i;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the month with the lowest rainfall.
 */
public int getLowestMonth() {
    int lowest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (months[i] < months[lowest]) {
            lowest = i;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
}
```

Rain class only has the main method now

```
public class Rain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an array of rainfall figures.
    double[] thisYear = { 1.6, 2.1, 1.7, 3.5, 2.6, 3.7, 3.9, 2.6, 2.9, 4.3,
            2.4, 3.7 };

    int high; // The high month
    int low; // The low month

    // Create a RainFall object initialized with the figures
    // stored in the thisYear array.
    Rainfall r = new Rainfall(thisYear);

    // Display the statistics.
    System.out.println("The total rainfall for this year is "
            + r.getTotalRainFall());
    System.out.println("The average rainfall for this year is "
            + r.getAverageRainFall());
    high = r.getHighestMonth();
    System.out.println("The month with the highest amount of rain " + "is "
            + (high + 1) + " with " + r.getRainAt(high) + " inches.");
    low = r.getLowestMonth();
    System.out.println("The month with the lowest amount of rain " + "is "
            + (low + 1) + " with " + r.getRainAt(low) + " inches.");
  }
 }
```

hope this helps

Comment: that works perfectly! Can you please explain to me why you needed to add in the extra detail with the getRainAt method? Thanks so much!

Comment: what getRainAt method does is , it takes the month value as integer, and iterate the months double array which has the rain fall values as array for the year and return the rainfall value based on array index getting equal to month number..

Comment: in your implementation getRainAt is a double array whereas I have created a specific method for it. Calling this method I utilized the double array containing rainfalls to find the correct fain fall value

Comment: and what does the months = newmonths part do?

Comment: Rainfall object constructor where the constructor argument (a double array) passed when the object is instantiated gets assigned to the month double array

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are creating a getRainAt class just to initialise it, try using the Rain class constructor to do this.

Replace this:

```
public class getRainAt {
    public getRainAt() {
    getRainAt = new double[12];
    }
}
```

With:

```
public Rain() {
    getRainAt = new double[12];
}
```

and since you are using Rain instead of Rainfall now, in the main method it should be:
    Rain r = new Rain();

Comment: Thanks for that. I have updated it, but am still getting errors. Is there a problem with the variable r?

Comment: Should it be Rain r = new Rain? (I've added this to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was just a copying error, but in the second block you've called the class `Rain`, but then you declared r as `Rainfall`.